# Play 2.0 Framework - find all that haven't expired

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to figure out how I can go about finding members of a list - but only ones that haven't past their expired date - which is one of the properties of the model.

Right now I have:

```
public static Result getAllNotifications() {
 List<Notification> notifications = Notification.getAllNotifications();

 for (Notification i: notifications) {
     List<Attachments> attachments = Attachments.findAllById(i.id);
     i.attached = attachments;
 }

    return ok(toJson(notifications));
}
```

Somewhere in there I need to check the expiration date of an individual notification and not return it if today is past that date.

Right now that model for a notificatin looks like this:

```
public class Notification extends Model {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@NonEmpty
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String title;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date created = new Date();

@Constraints.Required
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
public String text;

@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date updated = new Date();

public Boolean status;

public Date expires;

public String author;

public List<Attachments> attached;

public Notification() {
}

public Notification(Long id, String title, String text) {
    this.created = new Date();
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
    this.id = id;
}

public static Model.Finder<String, Notification> find = new Model.Finder<String,     Notification>(String.class, Notification.class);
```

This is my first ever Stackoverflow post so go easy on me! And thank you, in advance, for the help!

Comment: Can't you simply test if i.expires is < than the current Date?

Comment: Exactly ! That's the purpose of a Relationnal Model, to be "query-able" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, you're looking for all rows which `expires` date is bigger than current one `OR` it's `null` (not set), right?

In such case you can just use simple DB comparission (iterating whole resultset is definitely **WRONG idea!**)

- `gt` stands for `Greater Than`
- `lt` for `Lower Than`

in your model add finders:

```
// If expires date is grater than current one, the Notification IS expired
public static List<Notification> findAllExpired() {
    return find.where().gt("expires", new Date()).findList();
}

// If expires date is lower than current one OR isn't set at all,
// the Notification is valid.
public static List<Notification> findAllNotExpired() {
    return find.where().or(
              Expr.lt("expires", new Date()),
              Expr.isNull("expires")
           ).findList();
}
```

So you'll get the list not expired (or not expired) notifications in your controller:

```
List<Notification> notExpiredList = Notification.findAllNotExpired();

// check in terminal
for (Notification notification : notExpiredList) {
    Logger.info("This Notification IS NOT expired: " + notification.title);
}

List<Notification> expiredList = Notification.findAllExpired();

// check in terminal
for (Notification notification : expiredList) {
    Logger.warn("This Notification IS expired: " + notification.title);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterator and remove all notifications that are expired.

something like this:

```
    public static Result getAllNotifications() {
      List<Notification> notifications = Notification.getAllNotifications();

      Iterator<Notification> iterator = notifications.iterator();

      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Notification next = iterator.next();
        if (new Date().after(next.expires)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
      }


      for (Notification i: notifications) {
        List<Attachments> attachments = Attachments.findAllById(i.id);
        i.attached = attachments;
      }

      return ok(toJson(notifications));
  }
```

if the List is immutable you could return a filtered copy of it.

Comment: you may eventually encounter a OutOfMemoryException, since you load a lot of objects in the memory.

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly Jonas!! Many, many thanks for your help my friend!

Comment: Consider what will happen if you'll try to check 3 millions notifications that way...

Comment: @pixelworlds you should go with the solution `biesior` suggested. My solution is the quick and dirty version. The proper way of doing it is what `biesior` wrote. I didn't go into the details of the play framework way of accessing a SQL database. What you want to do is exactly what databases are made for, so you should use their features. Thanks for your answer (and comment) `biesior`